# Why the result of these two similar code calculating determinant is different?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function to calculate a determinant. The matrix are all 4x4 two-dimensional array. I found the following two pieces of codes have different results. I verify the result by MATLAB.

I use a test example like this

> 0 2 0 1
>
> 3 3 2 1
>
> 3 2 4 0
>
> 2 2 1 1

Code that have the right result:

```
void determinant()
    {
        double result=1;
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<4;j++)//swap the largest number to diagonal position
            {
                if(matrix[j][i]>matrix[i][i])
                {
                    swap_row(i,j);
                    result=result*(-1);//once swap two rows, result will multiply by (-1)
                }
            }
            for(j=i+1;j<4;j++)
            {
                double divident=matrix[j][i]/matrix[i][i];
                for(k=0;k<4;k++)
                {
                    matrix[j][k]=matrix[j][k]-matrix[i][k]*divident;//here is the different part
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            result=result*matrix[i][i];
        }
        cout<<"determinant="<<result<<endl;
    }
```

Thw right code change the matrix into this:

> 3 3 2 1
>
> 0 2 0 1
>
> 0 0 2 -0.5
>
> 0 0 0 0.25

However, once I write this code without `double divident=matrix[j][i]/matrix[i][i];`, result will turn different:

```
void determinant()
    {
        double result=1;
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<4;j++)//swap the largest number to diagonal position
            {
                if(matrix[j][i]>matrix[i][i])
                {
                    swap_row(i,j);
                    result=result*(-1);//once swap two rows, result will multiply by (-1)
                }
            }
            for(j=i+1;j<4;j++)
            {
                for(k=0;k<4;k++)
                {
                    matrix[j][k]=matrix[j][k]-matrix[i][k]*matrix[j][i]/matrix[i][i];//here is the different part
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            result=result*matrix[i][i];
        }
        cout<<"determinant="<<result<<endl;
    }
```

And the wrong code change the matrix into this

> 3 3 2 1
>
> 0 2 0 1
>
> 0 0 4 0
>
> 0 0 0 1

As for the function`swap_row`, it works like this(and I'm sure the problem doesn't exist here):

```
void swap_elements(double &a, double &b)
{
    double tmp;
    tmp=a;
    a=b;
    b=tmp;
}

void swap_row(int i, int j)
{
    for(column=0;column<4;column++)
    {
        swap_elements(matrix[i][column],matrix[j][column]);
    }
}
```

I use `this->display()`(the function is a mumber function in class) to track the changes step by step, but it appears that the calculation is nothing wrong, but the order is different(the right code calculates by row but the wrong one calculate by single element in the array) What makes me confused is that I didn't change anything about the loop. So what's the difference between these two codes?

Comment: what is the type of your `matrix` array?

Comment: @KamolHasan It's a `double matrix[4][4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in the second variant of your code you are overwriting things in a bad way. Consider the loop over `k`, assume `i=0` and look at the case `k=0`:

```
matrix[j][0]=matrix[j][0]-matrix[0][0]*matrix[j][0]/matrix[0][0];
```

This will overwrite entry `matrix[j][0]`. Now consider the next iteration of the same loop, i.e., `k=1` and still `i=0`:

```
matrix[j][1]=matrix[j][1]-matrix[i][1]*matrix[j][0]/matrix[0][0];
```

As you can see, this uses the element `matrix[j][0]` that you just updated in the previous iteration. So you are using the *new* value here. In the correct version of your code you instead store the value of `matrix[j][0]` before you start the loop and thus use the correct, non-updated value throughout the loop.